# Trouble using "Clip Raster by Mask Layer" algorithm QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdalwarp

[image]

I'm having issues using the "Clip Raster by Mask Layer" algorithm to clip a raster by a shapefile. When I run the algorithm, I get an error saying that the mask layer could not be loaded, even though it is already present in the legend. I've tried this after freshly opening it as well.

Though I can't go into the details about the process, I can tell you that a shapefile with the boundary of a field is used to make a 20ft inner buffer. This is then cut away from the original boundary file to make a new boundary that is 20ft smaller on every side than the original. This is then used to cut a very large raster with the Clip raster by mask layer. So it goes:

1. Boundary (shapefile) --[SAGA:Shapes Buffer (Fixed Distance)]-> Inner Buffer
2. Boundary + Inner Buffer  --[ QGIS:Symmetrical Difference]-> SymDif (Shapefile)
3. Raster + SymDif --[GDAL:ClipRasterByMask]-> clippedRaster

Step 3 is where I get the errors. Sometimes it just doesn't write any file (probably going to make another post about that), but in this case, it can't read the output from step 2 (SymDif file).

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the mask layer and the raster layer are both using the same CRS?

Comment: They are in the same CRS. I'm working a process that has been laid out for me, and should work. This process was used to make these files once and should make them again. I've tried every iteration of saving temp files or named ones and none make a difference. Gives the same error about not being able to find files.

Comment: What happens when you use the clipper tool from the Raster menu at the top of your screen with the same datasets? Raster > Extraction > Clipper

Comment: That also gives me an error with not being able to open up the mask layer. "Cannot open C:/Users/Berkh/Documents/Edmonds Farm Example|layername=8 difference or shrunk boundary. "

Comment: Hmm makes me think there is something up with the clipping mask,  btw what format is the clipping mask?   The path to the layer looks a bit odd to me. What happens if you convert the mask to a shapefile,  and use the path to the shapefile as the clipping mask?

Comment: Yeah, it's cut off... I have been getting similar issues  with the algorithm history menu, where it cuts off after the first line of algorithm inputs and only writes the first two parameters of the algo. Maybe there is a library corrupted somewhere for handling references? 

The mask is already a shapefile, not sure what you mean...

Comment: Sorry about that. I mean i'm curious why the path to your mask layer is something along the lines of "layername=8 difference or shrunk boundary" and not something that looks like <layername>.shp

Comment: I'm not sure either. I've tried adding the shape file immediately before use and it still does not work. Does QGIS care about empty spaces in file name?

Comment: Not sure about spaces in file names. I know many years ago ArcView didn't like it, not sure if its still an issue or if its an issue in QGIS. I think it is worth a try.

Comment: Also you mentioned before that you are working a process that has been laid out for you. Any chance you can list or outline that process in your question so we can see the workflow?

Comment: I'm very suspicious of the | and the = in the path for the file GDAL can't open, as per the error message. Are those things QGIS added via the GUI? maybe try the same command on the GDAL command line tool, but with a path without those special characters. Also, a good idea to not start the names of rasters with a number (throws some ArcGIS tools, if you ever use those).

Comment: The files are all added by command line using a PyQGIS script. 
Good to know on the numbers. I'm mainly working on QGIS, but may switch to ArcGIS. Is that platform more stable than QGIS?

Comment: Area you able to load the output from step 2 into a separate QGIS project just to make sure there is something there? - Also apologies I wasn't aware you were doing this in pyqgis, the title of the question must have been edited at some stage I assume.

Comment: Yes, the file write into an output folder along with all of the other files made.  I should have included PyQGIS in the title, it is in the tag though. Is there another work path that would allow you to clip a raster with 4 bands of info by a shape file? I have most of the things working, but this one step is holding everything back.

Comment: Yeah there are other methods like the one I mentioned previously via the Raster menu. Just for testing purposes you should be able to use the output from your step 2 to clip the raster with that tool. However from the information provided I think the file path to your mask is not correct, or it's not being referenced correctly in your code.

Comment: @Berkh - Apologies, I also wasn't aware that you were using PyQGIS. You should probably [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/199724/edit) your question to include some code, otherwise we might not know if the code is the issue or something else :)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like there might be an issue when you:

- Save the output as a *temporary file* **and**
- Check the `Open output file after running algorithm` option.

I would suggest saving the output as a normal file instead of a temporary one, works for me.

Comment: I've tried the same. Still getting an error with loading the input file. Is there some initializing step I'm missing? What confuses me is that these files were fresh loaded in and all references were made by QGIS.